# Gearman persistent storage solutions

Tags: persistence, gearman

What is the optimal way to introduce a data persistance system in gearman with optimal performance in mind?

I'm asking because we are thinking of moving away from our queue system in mysql and moving to gearman. It seems rather odd to use a relational database again for persisting data in the queue so we are looking for other possibilities.

I know of libdrizzle, libsqlite, etc ... but i'm thinking more into nosql, what are good, proven and stable solutions?

Answer (score -1):

if you do

```
$ gearmand -h
```

it should show you what queue options you have..

I think the only no-sql option available by default is memcached.

Comment: memcached isnt nosql, nor is it the only option. TokyoCabinet is there